# java - Regex to split a string containing multiple groups

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to split this string

```
(2005)[1]1,2,3,4[2]1(2008)[2]2–;3,4(2009)[3]1,2,3-4(2010)[4]1,2,3-4(2011)[5]1(2012)[5]2,3-4[6]1,2\[\](2014)[6]3-4[7]1-2(2015)[7]3-4[8]1-2(2016)[10]1[8]3-4[9]1-2,3-4(2017)[10]2
```

As:

```
1, "1,2,3,4"  
2, 1 2
2, 2–;3,4
```

For the input "(2005)[1]1,2,3,4" I need value in [ ] in capture group 1 and the rest of the string (1,2,3,4) in capture group 2 and repeat for the entire string

I have created this regex string but it is not working as intended

```
\[(.*?)\](.+?)(?=\[|\(|$)
```

[Please see my regex implementation](https://www.debuggex.com/r/eDlrxb-x8La4UVP0)

The problem is when there is nothing after [] it is capturing (year) which it should not do

Comment: Try [`\[([^\]\[]*)\]([^\[(]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/BOjcip/1). Also, you might as well replace `.+?` with `.*?` in your pattern.

Comment: it worked perfectly thanks a lot

Comment: I have created a [regex101 fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/nrg29Z/1), but can't make head or tails of what you mean now. Please provide exact output for each test case.

Comment: so for the first example in test case i want to parse the data to generate this output

"2015","5","1" \n
"2015","3","22,23,24" \n
"2015","8","1,2,3"

Comment: See [this version](https://regex101.com/r/BOjcip/4), is it capturing the right values?

Comment: it is working great, thank you for you time @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Do you need help with the code? You need to iterate thru the maches, check if Group 1 is not empty or null, and if it is not, you start a new entry. Fill it out until a match has no Group 1 set.

Comment: yep thats is what i am trying to do now, previously i was splitting the year and then splitting with regex so now i am basically doing every thing using regex and keeping the year until new year is found. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(.+?)(?=\[|\(|$)` part of the pattern matches any 1 or more chars other than a newline up to  the leftmost `[`, `(` or end of string. You need to allow matching *zero* or more chars here.

However, a `[^\[(]` negated character class here will be more efficient and elegant:

```
\[(.*?)\]([^\[(]*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BOjcip/2).

Or a bit more efficient,

```
\[([^\]\[]*)\]([^\[(]*)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BOjcip/3).

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[`
- `([^\]\[]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\]` - a `]`
- `([^\[(]*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `[` and `(`.

Comment: it is working fine for most of the values but in case of (2005)

[1]1,2,3,4[2]1(2008)[2]2–;3,4(2009)[3]1,2,3-4(2010)[4]1,2,3-4(2011)[5]1(2012)[5]2,3-4[6]1,2[](2014)[6]3-4[7]1-2(2015)[7]3-4[8]1-2(2016)[10]1[8]3-4[9]1-2,3-4(2017)[10]2(2011)[40](1-4)(2012)[41]0(2013)[42]1-4(2014)[43]0(2015)[44]1-4,1-2(2017)[46]

it is not picking up (1-4)
can you help with that please?

Comment: Replace `[^\[(]*` with `[^\[(]*(?:\(\d+-\d+\)[^\[(]*)*` or a more generic `[^\[(]*(?:\((?!\d{4}\))[^()]*\)[^\[(]*)*`. It would be better if you could explain what kibd of value you expect after the number in brackets. Note I'm on a mobile now and cannot check if my pattern works well or not.

Comment: so i expect 
a- year or empty brckts

b- anythinghere or empty brckts

c- somethinghere.

The format can be any of the below
(a)[b]c
(a)[b]c[b]c[b]c
(a)[b]c(a)[b]c[b]c
(a)[b](a)[b]c[b]c

Comment: I have updated the question with the possible format.

I need to split the string so i can match it as group1 -> year, group2 -> val in [ ], group3 -> comma seperated values

Comment: can you please update the expression so it can capture 1- anything in ( ), 2 - anything in [ ] 3- comma seperated values after [ ]

Comment: I 've also added test cases above, btw forgot to say thanks, for your help @wiktor-stribiżew